# How to change font size of jupyter notebook in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook to create python notes(sort of) for a virtual lecture. I like to use vscode instead of jupyter lab. But unfortunately the font size of the markdown output is too small(to see on participants' screen on virtual call).

While using jupyter lab, i used to zoom the whole browser. But i can't do that in vscode, also i can't find any setting that changes the font size for it.

The setting to change font size only applies to the vs code editor window.

Does anyone has any idea on how i can increase the size.

[image]

P.S.- I know that we could use `#` on each line to increase its size but i can't go around putting `#` before every line as i have to make a rather large document. And you get the idea how small the standard size is from the image.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A new setting is being added to vscode:

`notebook.markup.fontSize`

Should be in the Insiders Build v1.63 soon.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/126294#issuecomment-964601412

Comment: Just tested and it works perfectly. Create a file under `.vscode/settings.json` and add/append `{ "notebook.markup.fontSize": 14 }` (for example). Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

click on **gear icon** **top right**, and **select customize notebook layout**. in new windows that open you can change the font size.

Answer (score 2):

For one, we can zoom in the window using `ctrl and +`.

But this leads to another problem of making all the elements in the window larger, such as the sidebars and menu bars.

By the way, changing the editor font size only changes the editable code block. Changing markdown preview font size also does not help.

Answer (score 0):

They are considering of it, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1251)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your block into a div block and set font size to this block using css:

```
<div style=style="font-size: 12px">
   
     //your stuffs here

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).